# Toastr notification not appearing when called

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, toastr

I tried the following code but nothing's popping up when I launch the page in my browser

```
$(function () { //ready
    toastr.info('For more information, see our FAQ guide located below.');
});
```

Comment: pls provide the full html page code or fiddler demo or at least error from chrome developer tools

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you've included jQuery, toastr.js, *and* toastr.css in your page, then this should work.  I'd make sure to check to see if your path to these scripts are all correct, and I'd check the console for any errors.

```
<script src="/example-path-to/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="/example-path-to/toastr.js"></script>
<link href="/example-path-to/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
      $(function () { //ready
          toastr.info('If all three of these are referenced correctly, then this should toast should pop-up.');
      });
</script>
```

Comment: its shown but nothing displayed just white popup and nothing to say

Comment: @zolfaghari - You should post as separate question, not as comment.